# How to Invoke/Call AngularJS WebClient App from a Delphi Window Application?

Tags: angular, delphi, webclient, http-token-authentication

A WebClient (developed using AngularJS) having single page is hosted on a IIS server .
I want to know how to call that Web Client, which needs a Authentication token, from Delphi (version Berlin 10.1) Windows Application and show the UX to user?